# Covariance of two variable ,$Cov[T,R]$,Where $R=T+X$

Tags: probability

Assume a random variable $R=T+X$,where T is a Gaussian random variable with $E[T]=0$ and $VAR[T]=9$,and X is independent of T with PDF

$f_x(x)$=$\frac{1}{6}$ for $-3 \le x \le 3$

Find $Cov[T,R]$

I know $Cov[T,R]$=$E[T,R]-E[T]E[R]$,but i don't know how to calculate $E[T,R]$

Comment: There's no such thing as $E[T, R]$. You probably mean $E[TR]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\text{Cov}$ is biadditive in the sense that: $$\text{Cov}(U+V,W)=\text{Cov}(U,W)+\text{Cov}(V,W)\tag1$$ and: $\text{Cov}(U,V+W)=\text{Cov}(U,V)+\text{Cov}(U,W)\tag2$

This of course under the condition that the covariances on the RHS exist.

Applying that here we find:$$\text{Cov}(T,R)=\text{Cov}(T,T+X)=\text{Cov}(T,T)+\text{Cov}(T,X)=\text{Var}(T)+0=9$$

The only thing that has to be checked is that $\text{Cov}(X)$ exists, wich is not really difficult.

---

There is no need for calculation $\mathbb ETR$ (if that's what you mean).

If you insist on doing so then make use of $$\mathbb ETR=\mathbb E(T^2+TX)=\mathbb ET^2+\mathbb ETX=\mathbb ET^2+\mathbb ET\mathbb EX$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[ TR\right]=&\mathbb{E}\left[ T(T+X)\right] \\
= & \mathbb{E}\left[ T^2+TX)\right] \\
= &  \mathbb{E}\left[ T^2\right] +\mathbb{E}\left[TX\right] \\
= & 9 + \mathbb{E}\left[T\right]\mathbb{E}\left[X\right] \\
= & 9+0 \\
= & 9
\end{split}
In the thrid line we used the fact that if $T \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\mathbb{E}\left[ T^2\right]=\text{Var}(T)-(\mathbb{E}\left[T \right])^2=\sigma^2-\mu^2$, and also the fact that $T$ and $X$ are independent so we can factor the expectation of their product.